# Increment value in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

Here is the sample code for what I am trying to do and below is the result:

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.#TempDoc_DocContRoles (DocID int null, FullName varchar(500), DocContRole 
     varchar (100), NumRole int null)

   INSERT INTO #TempDoc_DocContRoles(DocID, FullName, DocContRole) 

      SELECT 
          d.DocID, c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as FullName, ldcro.DocContRole 
      FROM 
          Document as d 
      JOIN 
          dbo.Split( ',','30,31') AS l ON d.DocID = cast(l.[Value] AS int)
      JOIN 
          Doc_Contact AS dc ON d.DocID = dc.DocID 
      JOIN 
          Contact AS c ON dc.P_Number = c.P_Number 
      LEFT JOIN 
          lkpDocContactRole AS ldcro ON ldcro.DocContRoleID = dc.DocContRoleID 
      JOIN 
          dbo.Split( ',','1,2,7') AS r ON ldcro.DocContRoleID = cast(r.[Value] AS int)


   CREATE TABLE dbo.#MaxNumRoles (DocID int null, DocContRole varchar(100), NumRole int null)

   INSERT INTO  dbo.#MaxNumRoles (DocID,DocContRole,NumRole)
      SELECT 
          DocID, DocContRole, COUNT(*) 
      FROM 
          dbo.#TempDoc_DocContRoles 
      GROUP BY 
          DocID, DocContRole 
      HAVING 
          Count(*) > 0

   UPDATE td 
   SET td.NumRole = mr.NumRole
   FROM dbo.#TempDoc_DocContRoles as td
   INNER JOIN dbo.#MaxNumRoles as mr ON td.DocContRole = mr.docContRole 

   SELECT * FROM   dbo.#TempDoc_DocContRoles

   DROP TABLE dbo.#TempDoc_DocContRoles   
   DROP TABLE dbo.#MaxNumRoles
```

Result:

```
DocID   FullName    DocContRole NumRole
30      Smith    Author         3
30      Daln     Staff          2
30      Dolby    Author         3
31      Tammy    Author         3
30      Barny    Author         3
30      Sanny    Res Coor       1
30      Johny    Staff Rev      2
```

I would like to actually get:

```
DocID   FullName    DocContRole NumRole
30      Smith    Author         1
30      Daln     Staff          1
30      Dolby    Author         2
31      Tammy    Author         1
30      Barny    Author         3
30      Sanny    Res Coor       1
30      Johny    Staff Rev      2
```

It should increment the number in `NumRole` per `docContRole` and `docID` (ex Author 1, Author 2 etc). Currently it gives the total number of authors per `DocID`.

My ultimate goal is to get something like

```
       DocID    Author_1  Author_2 Author_3 Staff_1 Staff_2 ResCoor_1
30              Smith      Dolby    Barny    Daln    Johny    Sanny 
31              Tammy
```

Comment: Do you really need dynamic number of columns? You can get data into a ; delimited strings instead

Comment: Yes. I don't know what is the number of different roles.

Comment: Yes, but how you will use dynamic columns? I've added an answer, may be it will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
select
    td.DocID, td.FullName, td.DocContRole,
    row_number() over (partition by td.DocID, td.DocContRole order by td.FullName) as NumRole
from dbo.#TempDoc_DocContRoles as td
```

So dynamic SQL will be smth like that

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9b8a/14)

```
create table #t2
(
    DocID int, FullName nvarchar(max), 
    NumRole nvarchar(max)
)

declare @pivot_columns nvarchar(max), @stmt nvarchar(max)

insert into #t2
select
    td.DocID, td.FullName,
    td.DocContRole + 
    cast(
        row_number() over 
        (partition by td.DocID, td.DocContRole order by td.FullName)
    as nvarchar(max)) as NumRole
from t as td

select
    @pivot_columns = 
    isnull(@pivot_columns + ', ', '') + 
    '[' +  NumRole + ']'
from (select distinct NumRole from #t2) as T

select @stmt = '
select *
from #t2 as t
pivot
(
min(FullName)
for NumRole in (' + @pivot_columns + ')
) as PT'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I took an older example and tried to accomodate to what I need now. First what I thought of doing (what I did before with simpler case) is bring record with column NumRole to vba and then do my manipulation there in order to export to Excel in format that I have shown as ultimate goal. But i am now thinking if tehre is the option of doing it in sql and then just export to excel through vba.

Comment: This code of yours gives me what I wanted. I wonder how I can from this now do some kind of a pivot to get it to my goal.

Comment: Well you can use dynamic sql to get dynamic number of columns, if you're really sure you want this

Comment: Do you have a better approach to suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done without dynamic SQL. I've changed an answer - check it out

Comment: I have additional question. I have tested the code provided for the case when an empty recordset will be returned. As a result I got just (0 row(s) affected)  (0 row(s) affected).I expected to see column names and no records. Thanks