# T:SQL: select values from rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table for Profiles stores profile properties values in row style, ex:

```
[ProfileID]     [PropertyDefinitionID]      [PropertyValue]
1               6                           Jone
1               7                           Smith
1               8                           Mr
1               3                           50000
```

and another table for property definitions :

```
[PropertyDefinitionID]  [PropertyName]
6                       FirstName
7                       LastName
8                       Prefix
3                       Salary
```

How to use `PIVOT` or any other way to show it in this way:

```
[ProfileID] [FirstName] [LastName]  [Salary]
1           Jone        Smith       5000
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's easy to do this without `PIVOT` keyword, just by grouping

```
select
    P.ProfileID,
    min(case when PD.PropertyName = 'FirstName' then P.PropertyValue else null end) as FirstName,
    min(case when PD.PropertyName = 'LastName' then P.PropertyValue else null end) as LastName,
    min(case when PD.PropertyName = 'Salary' then P.PropertyValue else null end) as Salary
from Profiles as P
    left outer join PropertyDefinitions as PD on PD.PropertyDefinitionID = P.PropertyDefinitionID
group by P.ProfileID
```

you can also do this with `PIVOT` keyword

```
select
    *
from
(
    select P.ProfileID, P.PropertyValue, PD.PropertyName
    from Profiles as P
        left outer join PropertyDefinitions as PD on PD.PropertyDefinitionID = P.PropertyDefinitionID
) as P
    pivot
    (
        min(P.PropertyValue)
        for P.PropertyName in ([FirstName], [LastName], [Salary])
    ) as PIV
```

**UPDATE**: For dynamic number of properties - take a look at [Increment value in SQL SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055295/increment-value-in-sql-select-statement/13055403#13055403)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, both methods solved this issue, however if we take performance into consideration, which one is faster?

Comment: Can someone explain to me how MIN is going to work without a numeric value like this answer shows?

Comment: as long as datatype is comparable you can apply min aggregate. You can compare strings, dates etc.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you might have an unknown number of `PropertyName's` that you need to turn into columns.  If that is the case, then you can use dynamic sql to generate the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(PropertyName) 
                    from propertydefinitions
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT profileid, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select p.profileid,
                  p.propertyvalue,
                  d.propertyname
                from profiles p
                left join propertydefinitions d
                  on p.PropertyDefinitionID = d.PropertyDefinitionID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(propertyvalue)
                for propertyname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/210df/2).

Comment: you don't need to use `for xml` when you just need to concat columns into variable. There also might be security issues when you trying to select data from table, for example, user can have permissions on procedure, but have no permissions on tables. Take a look at my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055295/increment-value-in-sql-select-statement/13055403#13055403

Comment: @RomanPekar there are a variety of different ways to concatenate columns, this is the method I choose to use.