# T-SQL:Transform variable number of rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, coalesce

When I run a SQL query which returns one column with variable number of rows returned, I'd like to transform each of the row into column VALUE (I don't mind what the column header/titles are).

E.g.

```
Column1
-------
a
b
c
d
e
```

I want a script which will transform the above into a table like:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
------------------------
a    b    c    d    e
```

(Note that I do not care for the column names).

I know I cannot user PIVOT as row numbers are not fixed (they are based on a SQL query).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103114/tsql-select-values-from-rows-as-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to pivot your results and include a counter in your column name.  Since I'm presuming you don't know the potential number of columns, you'll need to use Dynamic SQL to accomplish this.

This should be close using `ROW_NUMBER` to get the counter:

```
declare @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @colswithalias AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @colswithalias = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(col1) 
                          + ' AS Col' 
                          + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) as varchar(10))
                      FROM yourtable 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(col1)
                      FROM yourtable 
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT ' + @colswithalias + '
             from 
             (
                select col1 rn, col1
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(rn)
                for col1 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/789548/1)

Comment: a quick question: do you know how I can store the output of that execute(@query) into a temp table? Tried several ways but did not work!

Comment: Thanks so much for your super quick response! I tried that as well. My execute(@query) returns around 600 columns. So when I execute the temp table, I get the error msg: Cannot create a row of size 14397 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.