# How to change row to columns for a single column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with columns `ProjectId` and `InfoFile`, where `Infofile` is a  `varbinary` column. There can be many images for a project, stored in the `InfoFile` column.

I want to get all the images for a project in columns instead of rows.

A simple select query return results like this:

```
ProjectA  file1
projectA  file3
projectB  file10
projectB  file22
```

I want the result like below:

```
ProjectA  file1  file3
projectB  file10 file22
```

I need only the single field "Infofile' to be shown in rows.
Also if the infofile has null, then I dont want that to shown in column.

Other answers are for multiple fields, but here there is only one field.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103114/tsql-select-values-from-rows-as-columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103114/tsql-select-values-from-rows-as-columns) Does this give you any ideas?

Comment: Are there any other columns in this data?

Comment: Deepak, thanks. I got it working using your link.